# Datamart with data which shouldn't be summarized

Tags: database, database-design, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, datamart

how could structure datamart tables with the following problems:

**Dimension Tables:**

Person.

Time ( hour, minute, day, week).

**fact Table:**

group_of_indicators

The problem is that if I want to get information from a person in a week, I can't add the daily, because this information is obtained differently. In other words, the information is not sumarizable.

Same with all people in a given time, it isn't possible to add each person to get their indicators, because group information is obtained differently.

Is it possible to design a datamart with these restrictions? If the answer is yes How?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it's possible to design a data mart with non summarizable data.  However, it's not very useful.  It's only purpose would be to retrieve historical data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Have you got any idea how I can design it?. I've think in create differents time dimensions (In this case 4 dimensions - hour, minute, day, week), and for the people I think in design a dimension table that has type_group ( type : person, group).

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with the design without knowing more about the data.